# vue js incorrect component in layout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

I'm trying to implement a Vue application with vuetify that will support layouts. New to Vue so most likely some rookie mistake. My app structure is as follows:
**main.js**

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import { App } from './app'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import('../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css')

/* eslint-disable no-new */

console.log(router)

Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import routes from '../app/routes'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: routes
})
```

**app/index.js**

```
export { default as routes } from './routes'
export { default as vuex } from './vuex'
export { default as App } from './App'
```

**app/App.vue**

```
<template>
  <app-base-layout>
    <v-content slot="content">
      <v-container fluid="" fill-height="">
        <v-layout justify-center="" align-center="">
          <v-tooltip right="">
            <v-btn icon="" large="" :href="source" target="_blank" slot="activator">
              <v-icon large="">code</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span>Source</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </app-base-layout>
</template>

<script>
import AppBaseLayout from './AppBaseLayout'
export default {
  components: {
    AppBaseLayout
  },
  data: () => ({
  }),
  props: {
    source: String
  }
}
</script>
```

**app/AppBaseLayout.vue** (note the `<slot name="content"></slot>`)

```
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire" dark="">
    <v-navigation-drawer
      clipped=""
      fixed=""
      v-model="drawer"
      app="">

      <v-list dense="">

        <v-list-tile :to="{path: '/', params: {id: 'test'}}">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>home</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Home</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile :to="{name: 'accountsListView', params: {id: 'add'}}">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>dashboard</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Tester</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile @click.stop="dialog = true">
          <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="290">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title class="headline">Use Google's location service?</v-card-title>
              <v-card-text>Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.</v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" @click.native="dialog = false">Disagree</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="green darken-1" flat="flat" @click.native="dialog = false">Agree</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>settings</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Settings</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar app="" fixed="" clipped-left="">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Lost Memories</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>

    <slot name="content"></slot>

    <v-footer app="" fixed="">
      <span>&copy; 2018</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    drawer: null,
    dialog: false
  }),
  props: {
    source: String
  }
}
</script>
```

**app/accounts/routes.js**

```
import * as components from './components'

export default [
  {
    path: '/accounts',
    component: components.AccountsListView,
    name: 'accountsListView'
  },
  {
    path: '/accounts/create',
    component: components.CreateEditAccounts,
    name: 'createAccounts'
  },
  {
    path: '/accounts/edit',
    component: components.CreateEditAccounts,
    name: 'editAccounts'
  }
]
```

My **app/accounts/components/AccountsListView.vue** is absolutely the same as **App.vue** except the text in span tooltip is different (I’ve tried more radical changes as well for visibility).
Questions/problems:

1. Why isn't **AccountsListView.vue** displayed and I see **App.vue** when I visit `/accounts`?
2. Is my approach of reusing layout component even remotely correct, or am I reinventing the wheel and there is some other, "proper" way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1.

Check your `components.AccountsListView` in `app/accounts/routes.js`
 is null or not. Vue don't throw error when route's component is null. If its valid, then check your `App.vue` has `<router-view />` or not.

A2.

I think reusing layout by providing content slot is valid. But I will define the layout directly in `App.vue` and use `<router-view />` as `<slot />`. Then in the `routes`, I will define a `{ path: '/', component: Base }` or `{ path: '/', component: Welcome }`.

Comment: `console.log(components.AccountsListView)` returns a non-empty object

Comment: Okay, this time seem `App.vue` don't have `<router-view />`

Comment: Maybe you can replace your `App.vue` with `AppBaseLayout.vue`. Then `<slot name="content"></slot>` to `<router-view />`.

Comment: that's definitely close to truth, I was able to hit my **AccountListView** via `/accounts` url, but right now struggling to hit the **Index** component - route is fine and there are no errors but the layout doesn’t contain it for this page, any suggestions? I've defined them like this: `import IndexComponent from './IndexComponent'

var rt = {
  path: '/',
  component: IndexComponent,
  name: 'Index'
}

export default [...rt, ...accounts, ...budgets, ...transactions]`

Comment: `export default [...rt, ...accounts, ...budgets, ...transactions]` I think this syntax is wrong. You should just `export default [rt, accounts, budgets, transactions]` You can't spread object inside array. And I think you should not spread each route definition inside an object too. Since the last route will be the only route.